# np.mean(phDF.ram) raise eror

Tags: python, pandas

```
phoneinfo=np.array([['galaxy s8','android',64,4,140,'samsung',6],['lumia','windows',32,3,150,'microsoft',6],
                    ['xperia l1','android',16,2,180,'sony',5],['iphone7','ios',128,2,138,'apple',4],
                    ['u ultra','android',64,4,170,'htc',5],['galaxy s5','android',16,2,145,'samsung',5],
                    ['iphone 5s','ios',32,1,112,'apple',4],['moto g5','android',16,3,144.7,'motorola',5],
                    ['pixel','android',128,4,143,'google',5]])

phDF=pd.DataFrame(phoneinfo,index=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],columns=['name','os','capacity','ram','weight','company','inch'])

np.median(phDF.ram)
```

Error message:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'true_divide' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Comment: *what error*? Always post the full error message including the stack trace

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga   I got this running the codes: `TypeError: ufunc 'true_divide' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

Comment: yeah that was the thing i trying to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the dtype of your `ram` column is in `object` type, `np.median` can't work on it.

```
phDF.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 9 entries, 1 to 9
Data columns (total 7 columns):
 #   Column    Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------    --------------  ----- 
 0   name      9 non-null      object
 1   os        9 non-null      object
 2   capacity  9 non-null      object
 3   ram       9 non-null      object
 4   weight    9 non-null      object
 5   company   9 non-null      object
 6   inch      9 non-null      object
dtypes: object(7)
memory usage: 576.0+ bytes
```

You can do it by either of the following ways:

Try [`Series.median()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.median.html) instead:

```
phDF.ram.median()
```

Or convert the dtype to `int` before using `np.median`:

```
np.median(phDF.ram.astype(int))
```

Or use [`pd.to_numeric()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) to convert the column to numeric first:

```
np.median(pd.to_numeric(phDF.ram))
```

Result:

```
3.0
```